# ARKit - Error loading DAE file exported from Maya

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I'm currently developing an application related to `ARKit` on iOS 11.0 and XCode 9.0 Beta.

I have problem loading dae file which was exported from Maya 2017.

It's super weird since I can successfully load and display dae file downloaded from the internet.

Thanks for any information, much appreciated.

Below is part of my code:

```
SCNScene *ball = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"ball.dae"];

if(ball == nil)
    printf("Couldn`t load model successfully\n");

SCNNode *ballNode = [ball.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Cube" recursively:true];

[scene.rootNode addChildNode:ballNode];
```

Comment: @James P Thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this thing out, you got to place a light to show your object.